# How do I save cmd output from msbuild to a log file in a for loop?

Tags: cmd, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have several Visual Studio 2015 solution files that I would like to build using a command line. I would like the output stored in a single file

Here is the contents of a batch file that builds the solutions.

```
echo off

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

set _SCRIPT_DRIVE=%~d0
echo DRIVE %_SCRIPT_DRIVE%


set baseDir=%_SCRIPT_DRIVE%\Source\Service\4.0\Branches\ARES
echo baseDir =  %baseDir%


set buildLog=%baseDir%\Build.log


rem these are the directory names / solution name of the projects I want to build
rem you can build 'n' solutions and use your own instead of me giving you the solution and code
set thirdParty=Cert,ManagedHooks,NLog,Newtonsoft.Json,RabbitMQ,MDTE
echo.
echo building  %thirdParty%
echo.


for %%p in (%thirdParty%) do (
  echo.
  echo building %%p

  cd %%p

  set thirdPartySolutionFile=%%p%.sln
  echo solution file : %thirdPartySolutionFile%

  MSBuild %thirdPartySolutionFile% /t:Rebuild /m /p:Configuration=Debug > %buildLog%

  cd ..
)
```

I only get the last project build information stored in the log file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

>> is the answer

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_appending_files.htm

> overwrites the %buildLog% file.

>> will append the input to this file

so the line where you call the build tool and send the output to the file shoul d be changed to have the >> in it instead of >

```
MSBuild %thirdPartySolutionFile% /t:Rebuild /m /p:Configuration=Debug >> %buildLog%
```